# What are reaching fouls in the NBA?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

When a player tries to steal the ball from a dribbling player, the referees sometimes award a "reaching foul". I just can't see any difference between a steal and a foul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific foul that they're calling (and is often called a "reach in" foul) is the defensive player touching the offensive player ("making contact") in a disallowed way.  "Re-routing" as referred in the other answer is actually a different rule - that affects *all* players, but players guarding the player possessing the ball have a separate, more restrictive ruleset governing them.

Most defensive fouls consist of violations of this rule - basically, don't touch the player with the ball except in specifically allowed ways.

The rule is Rule 12, B, Section 1, (b).  Most of Section 1 (except the penalties) is reproduced below.

> Section I—Types
>
> > a. A player shall not hold, push, charge into, impede the progress of an opponent by
> >     extending a hand, arm, leg or knee or by bending the body into a position that is not normal.
> >     Contact that results in the re-routing of an opponent is a foul which must be called immediately.
> >
> > b. Contact initiated by the defensive player guarding a player with the ball is not legal.
> >     This contact includes, but is not limited to, forearm, hands, or body check.
> >
> > EXCEPTIONS:
> >
> > > (1) A defender may apply contact with a forearm to an offensive player with the ball
> > >       who has his back to the basket below the free throw line extended outside the
> > >       Lower Defensive Box.
> > >
> > > (2) A defender may apply contact with a forearm and/or one hand with a bent elbow
> > >       to an offensive player in a post-up position with the ball in the Lower Defensive
> > >       Box.
> > >
> > > (3) A defender may apply contact with a forearm to an offensive player with the ball
> > >       at any time in the Lower Defensive Box.
> > >
> > > The forearm in the above exceptions is solely for the purpose of maintaining a
> > >       defensive position.
> > >
> > > (4) A defender may position his leg between the legs of an offensive player in a postup
> > >       position in the Lower Defensive Box for the purpose of maintaining defensive
> > >       position. If his foot leaves the floor in an attempt to dislodge his opponent, it is a
> > >       foul immediately.
> > >
> > > (5) Incidental contact with the hand against an offensive player shall be ignored if it
> > >       does not affect the player’s speed, quickness, balance and/or rhythm.
> >
> > c. Any player whose actions against an opponent cause illegal contact with yet another
> >     opponent has committed the personal foul.
> >     d. A personal foul committed by the offensive team during a throw-in shall be an offensive
> >     foul, regardless of whether the ball has been released.
> >     e. Contact which occurs on the hand of the offensive player, while that hand is in contact
> >     with the ball, is legal.