# Smacking the ball down without hitting the opponent's hand when they hold the ball with two hands

Tags: rules, basketball

When my opponent holds the ball with two hands can I smack the ball down without hitting the hand?

Comment: I asked this question a awhile ago: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/what-are-reaching-fouls-in-the-nba

Comment: You can hit both hands and no ball whatsoever, and it's not a foul. When a hand is in contact with the ball, it counts as the ball.

Answer (score 0):

That is perfectly legal, so long as you don't hit their arms or hands as well, which would constitute a 'reach in' foul. You aren't allowed to touch an offensive player with the ball except in a few restricted ways - *slapping them isn't one of them*.

The [question linked](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/what-are-reaching-fouls-in-the-nba) by **Kevin Tinnemans** in the comments to your question has the official rules regarding permissible contact with the offensive player with the ball.